# Using CMake, how can I correctly export transitive dependencies for a header only library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to create a header only library which has dependencies on yaml-cpp and spdlog. I would like to provide a library that users can link against and it will link against spdlog and yaml-cpp without the user having to manually link against them. However when I try to build my cmake project it fails on the install command:

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "MyHeaderLibTargets" ...) includes target "MyHeaderLib" which requires target "yaml-cpp" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "MyHeaderLibTargets" ...) includes target "MyHeaderLib" which requires target "spdlog" that is not in any export set.
```

How do I include these in the export set? I would have thought that linking against them would have automatically provided these dependencies.

The reproducable example:

Project structure:

```
/project_root
  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- include
      |- MyHeaderLib
          |- MyHeaderLib.h
```

Top level CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(MyHeaderLib)

include(FetchContent)

# Fetch yaml-cpp
FetchContent_Declare(
    yaml-cpp
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp.git
    GIT_TAG 0.8.0  # Use the desired tag or commit
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(yaml-cpp)

# Fetch spdlog
FetchContent_Declare(
    spdlog
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
    GIT_TAG v1.9.2  # Use the desired tag or commit
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spdlog)


# Add MyHeaderLib library
add_library(MyHeaderLib INTERFACE)
target_sources(MyHeaderLib INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyHeaderLib/MyHeaderLib.h>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

# Set the include directories
target_include_directories(MyHeaderLib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(MyHeaderLib INTERFACE yaml-cpp spdlog)


# Install headers
install(DIRECTORY include/MyHeaderLib DESTINATION include)
# Install target and create export set
install(TARGETS MyHeaderLib EXPORT MyHeaderLibTargets)

# Generate and install the export set
install(EXPORT MyHeaderLibTargets
    FILE MyHeaderLibTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE MyHeaderLib::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyHeaderLib
)

# Install package configuration files
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyHeaderLibConfig.cmake
    INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyHeaderLib
)

install(FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyHeaderLibConfig.cmake
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyHeaderLib
)
```

Comment: Add `find_dependency(...)` in your cmake config and use namespaced target names.